# Suppress complexity warning in PHP

Tags: php, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a legacy code, for which the complexity of the code is higher than 20. My pipelines are failing due to this fact. This is the exact error message from the pipelines:

```
Function's cyclomatic complexity (36) exceeds allowed  maximum of 20
```

I don't have the time to refactor the code so, I am looking for a temporary solution like suppressing/ignoring my file:

I tried to use these:

```
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
```

or

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
my code here
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```

I also followed this [article](https://phpmd.org/rules/codesize.html) , but my pipelines are still failing. Have you ever faced such an issue before ? Do you have any idea how to fix this, **without** changing my pipelines settings/configurations?

Answer (score 1):

The OP did not mention whether the error came from PHPCS or PHPMD.  If it's coming from PHPCS, then this doc comment line will suppress the warning:

`* phpcs:disable Generic.Metrics.CyclomaticComplexity`

Answer (score 0):

I get the same warning as OP and I'm sure that it comes from PHPMD.
To suppress it I use PhpDoc comment before method:

```
/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function myComplexMethod(...)
```